# Can't load model from config file: no [nlp] section found. {'spacy': {'model': 'en_core_web_sm'}}

Tags: nlp, data-analysis, pdfminer, spacy-3

this is the error im getting below

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\nisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "D:\final year project\Smart_Resume_Analyser_App-master\Smart_Resume_Analyser_App-master\App.py", line 366, in <module>
    run()
File "D:\final year project\Smart_Resume_Analyser_App-master\Smart_Resume_Analyser_App-master\App.py", line 137, in run
    resume_data = ResumeParser(save_image_path).get_extracted_data()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyresparser\resume_parser.py", line 21, in __init__
    custom_nlp = spacy.load(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 54, in load
    return util.load_model(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 444, in load_model
    return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 516, in load_model_from_path
    nlp = load_model_from_config(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 557, in load_model_from_config
    raise ValueError(Errors.E985.format(config=config))
```

This is a cv analyzer application implemeted using *spaCy *and *streamlite*
when the user end tries uploadeing the cv it takes the cv into the application and process it but, encounters an error when analyzing the cv

attached below is the code for the analyzer

```py
## Get the whole resume data
                resume_text = pdf_reader(save_image_path)

                st.header("**Resume Analysis**")
                st.success("Hello "+ resume_data['name'])
                st.subheader("**Your Basic info**")
                try:
                    st.text('Name: '+resume_data['name'])
                    st.text('Email: ' + resume_data['email'])
                    st.text('Contact: ' + resume_data['mobile_number'])
                    st.text('Resume pages: '+str(resume_data['no_of_pages']))
                except:
                    pass
                cand_level = ''
                if resume_data['no_of_pages'] == 1:
                    cand_level = "Fresher"
                    st.markdown( '''<h4 style='text-align: left; color: #d73b5c;'>You are looking Fresher.</h4>''',unsafe_allow_html=True)
                elif resume_data['no_of_pages'] == 2:
                    cand_level = "Intermediate"
                    st.markdown('''<h4 style='text-align: left; color: #1ed760;'>You are at intermediate level!</h4>''',unsafe_allow_html=True)
                elif resume_data['no_of_pages'] >=3:
                    cand_level = "Experienced"
                    st.markdown('''<h4 style='text-align: left; color: #fba171;'>You are at experience level!''',unsafe_allow_html=True)

                st.subheader("**Skills Recommendation**")
                ## Skill shows
                keywords = st_tags(label='### Skills that you have',
                text='See our skills recommendation',
                    value=resume_data['skills'],key = '1')

                ##  recommendation
                ds_keyword = ['tensorflow','keras','pytorch','machine learning','deep Learning','flask','streamlit']
                web_keyword = ['react', 'django', 'node jS', 'react js', 'php', 'laravel', 'magento', 'wordpress',
                               'javascript', 'angular js', 'c#', 'flask']
                android_keyword = ['android','android development','flutter','kotlin','xml','kivy']
                ios_keyword = ['ios','ios development','swift','cocoa','cocoa touch','xcode']
                uiux_keyword = ['ux','adobe xd','figma','zeplin','balsamiq','ui','prototyping','wireframes','storyframes','adobe photoshop','photoshop','editing','adobe illustrator','illustrator','adobe after effects','after effects','adobe premier pro','premier pro','adobe indesign','indesign','wireframe','solid','grasp','user research','user experience']

                recommended_skills = []
                reco_field = ''
                rec_course = ''
```